# cannot access inherited property in object

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have a base class in separate project/Component like

```
public class Shape
{
  public int myTestproperty { get; set; }
}
```

then create another project include Shape Class component/DLL in created project and created another class and inherit that class with Shape class like

```
public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public int getArea()
    {
        return (width * height);
    }
}
```

and then when I create object of Rectangle class in same project like

```
Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle();
```

I cannot access my base class property  like

```
Rect.myTestproperty =1;
```

can some one tell me how I can access my base class property?

Comment: Are you sure that `Shape` in `Rectangle : Shape` is same as `Shape` in `public class Shape`? Move cursor on `Shape` in `Rectangle : Shape` and press `F12`.

Comment: Have you tried building the solution and check if the problem is resolved?

Comment: yes sure , by F12 its locate by base class, but remember my base class is in some other project

Comment: Search for "System.Windows.Shapes" in your code.  Did you find it?

Comment: The Shape/Rectangle is possibly derived from different namespaces (but just happen to have the same name)

Comment: oh yes i forget to mention that i am creating object in third project
i mean
 Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle();
in my Unit test project i mean

Comment: no i cannot find System.Windows.Shapes

Comment: put the full path namespace when inheriting e.g. `class Rectangle : <your-namespace>.Shape` - and call the e.g. `new <yournamespace>.Rectangle().myTestmethod()` - and see what happens - i.e. that should point you to the source of your problems, which is something mundane

Comment: Try this: Rename shape to Shape11, Rectangle to Rectangle11. Now see if the compiler throws up at  `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()`. If not then you are using the wrong Rectangle class from another assembly

Comment: No, Same Problem Remeber i have three different project my base class reside in one project , then in 2nd project i inherit my base class by referencing its DLL ,  and in third Unit Test project i just Reference my 2nd Project and by creating object or my 2nd class and then want to access my first class public property

Comment: Yes I understand that. Did you rename everything to add `11` to the end of them. Then do `var rect = new Rectangle11(); rect.myTestProperty = 1;` ? Also remember to rebuild the classes you change to build the dll again

Comment: cannot get rename every thing to add 11 to end of them ..... rebuilt serveral times

Comment: First Project 

namespace SLCloud.Accounting.Data.Models
{
    public class Shape
    {

        public int myTestproperty { get; set; }
      


    }
}


2nd Project 

namespace SLCloud.Accounting.Core.BLL
{
   
     public   class Rectangle : SLCloud.Accounting.Data.Models.Shape
    {
           
    }


  
     
    }



In Unit Test

    SLCloud.Accounting.Core.BLL.Rectangle Rect = new SLCloud.Accounting.Core.BLL.Rectangle();
           
          Rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying unnecessary solutions offered, you should use fully qualified reference of your Shape class. So try this: public class Rectangle : myNamespace.Shape. where myNamespace is namespace in your desired DLL. I gurantee this will resolve your problem for good. There is no way public property gets hidden unless you specially create designer class and remove that property or the following attributes are applied on the property: [Browseable(false),EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
If the propety is hidden using scenarios I mentioned above then only reflection can help you.

Comment: this is my code https://bitbucket.org/ZFAS/test
in Unit Test project i want to access property